# Can't add padding to images

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I'm unable to add padding to my social media icons in Dreamweaver CC 2015. I have very little experience with code, but need to finish an assignment at school by tonight. Basically, I need spaces in between my icons to look more visually appealing (20px would be ideal).The problem I'm having is that when I change the padding or margin of CSS, in split view, it shows how the spaces are being created but when I switch to live view, the spaces go back to 0px and same when I preview it.

**The Code:**

```css
.social-icon {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <center>
    <h4 class="footer" style="background-color: grey; width: 100%; padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 150px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/facebook.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://pinterest.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/pinterest.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/twitter.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://googleplus.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/gplus.png" width= "70px" height= "70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/youtube.png" width= "70px" height= "70px" class="social-icon"></a>
    </h4>
  </center>
</footer>
```

Comment: your images are not i a row. Do u want space in bottom of each image?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If this is a school project, then I understand. But otherwise, if you're not being forced at gunpoint to build a website using Dreamweaver, do yourself a favor and stop! O_O Learn fundamentals and you'll be the one helping others on SO :)

Comment: Speaking of DW, this has nothing to do with your choice of IDE.

Comment: Using the chrome browser, you can right click and inspect the images; Go to the "computed" tab on the right hand side of the developer panel, and you can hover over the little model to visualize your margins and paddings; This might help clear up how the margins and paddings are calculated in your project, and maybe help you see any problems.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.social-icon {
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;

}
```

```html
<footer>
  <center>
    <h4 class="footer" style="background-color: grey; width: 100%; padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 150px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/facebook.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://pinterest.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/pinterest.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/twitter.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://googleplus.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/gplus.png" width= "70px" height= "70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/youtube.png" width= "70px" height= "70px" class="social-icon"></a>
    </h4>
  </center>
</footer>
```

you want them to be align??

or you can do it with flexbox

```css
.footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.social-icon {
margin: 10px;

}
```

```html
<footer>
  <center>
    <h4 class="footer" style="background-color: grey; width: 100%; padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 150px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/facebook.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://pinterest.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/pinterest.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/twitter.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://googleplus.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/gplus.png" width= "70px" height= "70px" class="social-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="../Flikk/images/youtube.png" width= "70px" height= "70px" class="social-icon"></a>
    </h4>
  </center>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add padding to an image element. You can add it to it's parent but you'd still not see anything happen because of the margin. Why not just make `margin-right:200px;`?

Comment: Both you and Pimskie are wrong regarding image padding, it's perfectly normal to have it since it represents space between element and it's border.

Answer (score 0):

Since an `img` tag can't have any child elements, it can't have padding either. 
But can't you just simply add `margin: 10px;` to the images?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg9e6Lth/4/

Comment: I'm sorry for -1 but padding is space between element and border thus images and any element that can have border can have padding. So please check: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp before you down vote any other answers.

Comment: Ow if w3s says it!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it with bootstraps thumbnail class? just search for it you will find what you r looking for. 
[for thumbnail style it seems padded](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood question but this may quickly fix things.

Can you try changing your code to:

```
.social-icon {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

or

```
.social-icon {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```